# QT OCI driver isn't working with MSVC compiler

Tags: c++, oracle, qt

QT version 6.2.x
I have compiled the oci driver for MinGW and MSVC. It works with MinGW compiler but not with MSVC. When I use MSVC compiler in my project I get the error "QOCI driver not loaded".
The driver is compiled according to the instructions:
`qt-cmake.bat -G Ninja F:\Qt\6.2.0\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=F:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64 -DOracle_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\oracle\sdk\include" -DOracle_LIBRARY="C:\oracle\sdk\lib\msvc\oci.lib" cmake --build . cmake --install .`

Comment: I tried different params:
PATH=C:\oracle
ORACLE_HOME=C:\oracle
TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle
ORACLE_SID=orcl

Comment: It would be better to add the additional new info not in the comment but in the question. Also, consider using triple backticks to add a big lump of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed by using the VS Command Prompt.